# Neo4j 1.9: How connect to HA machines? by IP? What I can do when the machine failed?

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 1.9   ：How connect to HA machines? by IP ? What I can do when the machine failed ?

after 1.9 ,the Neo4j do not use zookeepers;
but if I connect to HA machines by IPs, whasome machine Crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most setups you want to have a loadbalancer component in front of the cluster. This can bei either a hardware lb or a software lb like ha_proxy, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/ha-haproxy.html